# Access Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm getting an Access Run-time error:

> '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1

when trying to run some VBA code from a form with sub-report.

I've tried with the variable (`CurAssetID`) as well as the direct link (`Forms!Details!ID`) in the SQL query but both result in the same error.  I put in the MsgBox just to verify it was picking up the correct value which it is.

If I replace the last part of the SQL query with a value (`HAVING (((Assignments.AssetID)=1));"`) it works fine.  What's going on here and how can I fix it?

```vb
Private Sub LineSelect_Click()
CurAssetID = Forms!Details!ID
Status = MsgBox(CurAssetID, vbOKOnly)
Dim LastAssignment As DAO.Recordset
LastAssignmentSQL = "SELECT Assignments.AssetID, Last(Assignments.LocationID) AS LastLocationID FROM Assignments GROUP BY Assignments.AssetID HAVING (((Assignments.AssetID)=CurAssetID));"
Set LastAssignment = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(LastAssignmentSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

Comment: Your SQL can't see your VBA parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a string variable with the parameter value concatenated inside it:

```vb
curAssetID = Forms!Details!ID
status = MsgBox(CurAssetID, vbOKOnly)
Dim lastAssignment As DAO.Recordset
lastAssignmentSQL = "SELECT Assignments.AssetID, " & _
                    "Last(Assignments.LocationID) AS LastLocationID " & _
                    "FROM Assignments " & _
                    "GROUP BY Assignments.AssetID " & _
                    "HAVING (((Assignments.AssetID)=" & CurAssetID & "));"
Set lastAssignment = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(lastAssignmentSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
' ...
```

As an additional precaution, if `Forms!Details!ID` is suposed to be a number (`Integer` or `Long`), I suggest you declare the variable `CurAssetID` explicitly:

```vb
Dim curAssetID as Integer ' Or Long
curAssetID = Forms!Details!ID
Dim lastAssignment As DAO.Recordset
lastAssignmentSQL = "SELECT Assignments.AssetID, " & _
                    "Last(Assignments.LocationID) AS LastLocationID " & _
                    "FROM Assignments " & _
                    "GROUP BY Assignments.AssetID " & _
                    "HAVING (((Assignments.AssetID)=" & CurAssetID & "));"
Set lastAssignment = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(lastAssignmentSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
' ...
```

If the value is a 'String', then you should enclose the value in quotes in your query:

```vb
Dim curAssetID as String
' ...
lastAssignmentSQL = "SELECT Assignments.AssetID, " & _
                    "Last(Assignments.LocationID) AS LastLocationID " & _
                    "FROM Assignments " & _
                    "GROUP BY Assignments.AssetID " & _
                    "HAVING (((Assignments.AssetID)= '" & CurAssetID & "'));"
' ...
```